# Biggest sum of steps for n stairs

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

This is a homework problem and it is DP, but it is not a 'how many ways are there to reach the nth-stair problem'.

Rather, in this problem each stair step is assigned a number from -10000 to 10000 so e.g. I have steps such as `-1 2 1`, and I have to find the biggest sum while being able to go up one step or skip one step each time. In that example that answer is `3` since I can skip the first step and then just visit the rest of the stairs.

I notice that I can always remove the last step since I have to step on it anyways.

How can I go about doing this in the dynamic programming fashion? Do I find the largest sum at each step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic programming as you know is all about asking the right questions.

Questions that should be asked here with an example:

a = [-5, -2, 1, 3]

What is the maximum value you can get if you step on 2 step(array index starting from zero) whose value is 1?

Let's define f[2] be the maximum value you can get till 2 steps.
So you have choices there; either you can step on it or you don't step on it.

```
If (step on 2 step in array index i.e 1)
    you can also step on previous step i.e -2 or skip the previous step
    if (you skip the previous step i.e -2)
        you need to step on previous to previous step i.e -5
```

From above you can see

```
   f[2] = max(a[2] + a[1] or a[2] + a[0])
```

I am also learning so I am not sure if below is right or not?

F[n] =max(F[n-1]+a[n], F[n-2]+a[n])

Comment: `F[n] = a[n] + max(F[n-1], F[n-2])` is a simplification of your equation.

Answer (score 1):

Set up an array of integers (or longs or whatever will hold plus or minus 10000*n) called `sum[n]`, the largest sum possible if you are standing on step `n`. Note that `sum[0]=step[0]` is the zeroth element of the array you are given, but `sum[1]= max{0+step[1],sum[0]+step[1]}` because you can reach step 1 either directly from the floor or by passing through the zeroth step. Now figure out a similar formula for `sum[2]`, and generalize. Then compute `sum[i]` in order.

I don't think you can just "remove the last step". You might have to step on it, and you can avoid it, whatever is best. You might want to introduce a fake last step with value 0, though.

Answer (score 0):

Just a clue:

Assume you want to reach step n. You could either go from step n-2 or n-1.

So F(n)=Max(F(n-2),F(n-1)) + x[n]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to ElKamina's answer, remember that whatever you choose to do at any stage (one or two steps forwards), the third item from there is reachable...